# Sharepoint alternative to GetUrlKeyValue() when using inplview.js API

Tags: javascript, jquery, spservices

Sharepoint offers the following JavaScript function to get a QueryString parameter value:

```
GetUrlKeyValue('a', false, 'www.example.com?a=test')
```

I would like to know if there is a similar JavaScript function to get a parameter value from within inplview.js API hashed url like the following:

```
http://www.example.com/testsite/Lists/SampleList/List.asp#InplviewHash7ed4366a-8857-4c61-b92f-6d6f635ad420=WebPartID%3D%7B38A3E939--9187--4C4A--BF28--0CEF3988314A%7D-FilterField1%3DFoo-FilterValue1%3DBar
```

From the previous URL, I would like to extract 'FilterField1' and 'FilterValue1' values ('Foo' and 'Bar' respectively), as if those were regular QueryString parameters.

Comment: JavaScript does not offer any function to get query string parameters. But you can create your custom function to get query string parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a built in function to achieveing this. So I wrote a very simple function to get what I need.

I post this as an answer but I'm still open to suggestions.

Thank you.

```
function GetUrlHashKeyValue(key) {
    var value = '',
        hash = window.location.hash,
        fv1Index = hash.indexOf(key + '%3D');

    if (fv1Index != -1) {

        value = hash.substr(fv1Index + key.length + 3);

        // value could end at the end of the string, or when another value comes right after
        // One dash "-" found means another parameter follows, only if it is not followed by another dash "--"
        // Double dash "--" is one dash escaped within a string.
        value = value.replace(/--/g, '||');

        // Now, if we find a single dash "-", it is delimiting a new parameter
        var dashFoundAt = value.indexOf('-');
        if (dashFoundAt != -1) {
            value = value.substring(0, dashFoundAt);
        }

        // Rollback our custom double dash escaping
        value = value.replace(/\|\|/g, '--');
    }

    return value;
}

var filterVal = GetUrlHashKeyValue('FilterValue1');
```

You might need to decode the result:

```
decodeURIComponent(filterVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

See the second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552944/how-to-get-the-anchor-from-the-url-using-jquery

Or do a search for "javascript read anchor".

Comment: Thank you. I know I can get the entire anchor from the URL, I just wanted to know if there is any built in function for parsing querystring-like parameters built in the anchor parameter when using inplview.js in Sharepoint.